# UseExceptionHandler vs UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've been reading about errors handling in ASP.NET Core and I came across these 2 ways:

- `UseExceptionHandler("/error")`
- `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/error/{0}");`

I'm wondering what's the difference between the two? Both redirect to an error page so why use one over the other? I even saw some people using them both at the same time.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are right that both middlewares do provide error pages. However, they have two different use cases which will make it useful to actually use both at the same time in an application. To understand the differences, let’s take a look at how the middlewares actually work internally.

This is essentially what the [StatusCodePages middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/2.1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/StatusCodePage/StatusCodePagesMiddleware.cs) does:

```
// …
await _next(context);
// …

// Do nothing if a response body has already been provided.
if (context.Response.HasStarted
    || context.Response.StatusCode < 400
    || context.Response.StatusCode >= 600
    || context.Response.ContentLength.HasValue
    || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Response.ContentType))
{
    return;
}

var statusCodeContext = new StatusCodeContext(context, _options, _next);
await _options.HandleAsync(statusCodeContext);
```

It executes the pipeline by calling `_next` and after the call has returned (meaning that all following middlewares have executed), it will inspect the current response: Basically, if there’s an error status code or no content at all, it will execute the status code page, signalizing the HTTP status code.

The [ExceptionHandler middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/2.1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs) on the other hand does something very different:

```
try
{
    await _next(context);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // …
    try
    {
        // …

        await _options.ExceptionHandler(context);

        // …
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {
        // Suppress secondary exceptions, re-throw the original.
        _logger.ErrorHandlerException(ex2);
    }
    throw; // Re-throw the original if we couldn't handle it
}
```

This will *try* to invoke the middleware pipeline and catch any exception it might produce. Then, it will attempt to run the registered exception handler (which, when setting a path basically means to invoke that path internally and return its response).

So to sum this up:

- The **StatusCodePages middleware** will handle non-successful *status code responses* and allows you to specify e.g. custom error pages for things like a 404 Not Found.
- The **ExceptionHandler middleware** on the other hand will catch *unhandled exceptions* in your application and allows you to handle those gracefully for the end user.

Both middlewares have different purposes and actually don’t overlap in what they do. So it often makes sense to include both of them, unless you handle these issues differently of course; e.g. an API will probably not need status code pages, but might still want an exception handler that returns a generic failure and logs everything properly.

Comment: Oh, I did not know ExceptionHandler can handle unhandled exceptions, this can be very helpful indeed. Perfect explanation, thank you.